What fraction of O in dry biomass comes from air vs water?
The net reaction of photosynthesis is, to some degree of approximation,
$$
\ce{6CO2 + 6H2O \to C6H12O6 + 6O2}.
$$
My understanding is that the $\ce{O2}$ comes from water rather than the $\ce{CO2}$, so that the equation breaks down like this
$$
\ce{6 C\color{red}{O2} + 6 H2\color{blue}{O} \to C6H12\color{red}{O6} + 3\color{red}{O2} + 3\color{blue}{O2}}.
$$
(See the answers to Why does the oxygen produced in the photosynthesis come from water and not carbon dioxide?) This suggests the $\ce{O}$ in plant biomass initially all comes from air ($\ce{CO2}$) and not from water ($\ce{H2O}$).
However, there are plenty of other processes in the cell that involve water besides photosynthesis, and I'm wondering whether any of them result in $\ce{O}$ from water being incorporated into biomass to any significant degree.
In other words, if we tagged the $\ce{H2O}$ in an ecosystem with an isotope of oxygen, how much of the isotope would end up incorporated into biomolecules in the long run, versus being expelled as $\ce{O2}$?
For the sake of keeping the question focused I'm only asking about a phototrophic ecosystem. If the answer is interesting I'll ask a separate one about chemoautotrophs.

An issue with this is that it's continually being recycled and mixed up. You seem to be after a snapshot, a picture of proportion in time? Tough to know how to measure that at any specific part of the day/night cycle, seasons and lifecycle. It's also quite unfocused asking about various different subjects. Can you narrow it? (that's assuming it even can be answered, I'm not enough of a chemist to understand how carbon dioxide and water interact to swap oxygen - or not)

@JiminyCricket it's a straightforward question: are there biological processes that replace O2 in cells (which originally came from air) with O2 from water? It might even be that the isotope experiment has been done and we know the answer. You can't really get more narrow and focused than that.

Well, perhaps start with autotrophs and binding of oxygen, then make  separate questions in their own threads (linking to this if you like)  regarding the rest of the food chain.

@JiminyCricket just to keep you happy I've removed the last paragraph, although I really don't think that should be necessary. I'm not going to split the question up by trophic level because that doesn't make sense. It's a question about ecology and you can't learn about ecosystems by studying each species separately.

Fair enough. I just thought it more likely you'd get a narrower estimate range if you narrowed the question, and it would be less likely to be closed as too broad.
